# Using common privilege helper tool across workspace- SMJobBless

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode6, smjobbless

I have a workspace which has 2 projects, one is installer application and other is uninstaller app.
Both the apps requires privilege helper tool for some operations. I am trying to write a common tool as a third project in my workspace that would be linked with the existing projects.

**Now, the question is how can i add that common tool in target dependency of existing projects and launch(privilege tool) it from other projects.**

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with this account, seems like nobody is happy to help on SO

Comment: Well, your question is not clear, and you're mixing stuff. `workspace` refers to the configuration of your project, while `privileges` are obtained at runtime.

Comment: To make sure I understood correctly: do you want to include your helper tool in other projects too without having to copy+paste it's source code and target settings?

Comment: @Cristik do you want to include your helper tool in other projects too without having to copy+paste it's source code and target settings? -- Yes, Exactly that's the purpose

Comment: Then just add the project that contains the helper tool within the other workspaces. If however you are using source control and have different repositories for projects, you can use the helper tool repository as a submodule to the other ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the project that contains the helper tool within the other workspaces, and then add the target corresponding to the helper tool as build dependency, as you want.

If however you are using source control and have different repositories for projects, you can use the helper tool repository as a submodule to the other ones. See [this article](https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/) for more on git submodules and how you can use them.